# Cookie does not properly get set

Tags: reactjs, node.js, firebase, express, cookies

I am using vite to create a react app that I deploy on firebase to only host the web app, I am using a nodeJS express backend, since I dont know where to deploy my server i just used ngrok on the port my server is running and forward all the requests from my frontend to the ngrok link it gave me which is https. The requests are successfully sent and the responses are sent back correctly, but the cookie it sends back is not correct, to be precise I think they are not beeing set. I saw that there were a few errors and changed the sameSite attribute to "none" and the secure attribute to "true" after that no errors appeared but the cookie still does not work. I need the cookie to authenticate the user requests.

Here's a link to the web app if you want to test it out yourself. I will leave the ngrok open probablly until the end of the day, after that the requests wont work. The register and login should work since they dont use cookies, and only the logbook is avaliable from the site nothing else is enabled. the logbook uses cookies to verify the client but since its not set correctly it doesn't work and it says that you need to login to access the content.
https://musclevol-3c5cc.web.app/

This is my server config file:

```
require("dotenv").config()
const mysql = require("mysql2")
const express = require("express")
const session = require("express-session")
const MySQLStore = require("express-mysql-session")(session)
const cors = require("cors")

const dbConnection = {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
};

const sessionStore = new MySQLStore(dbConnection);

const db = mysql.createConnection(dbConnection);

const sessionSettings = {
  secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
  store: sessionStore,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  name: "test-cookie",
  cookie: {
    secure: true,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: "none",
  },
};

const corsSettings = {
    origin: [process.env.FRONTEND_PRODUCTION, process.env.FRONTEND_PRODUCTION2],
    credentials: true,
}

const app = express();

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors(corsSettings))
app.use(session(sessionSettings))

module.exports = {
    db,
    app,
}
```

I tried to clear browser cache that was not the problem. I think it is because my site does not have an SSL certificate but I wouldn't know if that is the problem since I am very new to this stuff. Even tho I don't have an SSL certificate I want to just test my backend sicne I don't know where to deploy it for free.

Answer (score 0):

Remove secure flag from sessionSettings

```
 const sessionSettings = {
  secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
  store: sessionStore,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  name: "test-cookie",
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: "none",
  },
};
```

Your site does not have an SSL certificate. When secure is set to true, the cookie will only be sent over HTTPS connections.

Comment: I think the firebase web-app does have a certificate, atleast it says it does. I removed secure but still the cookie does not get set. this is an image of my network tab and my fetch request when i log-in:
https://prnt.sc/RXI0VTPQfO8r